# Few accepted answers at SE.DSP meta. Should we bother?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, unanswered-questions

We sometimes complain about SE.DSP posts, lacking of quality, upvoted or accepted answers. I just remarked that the level of accepted answers at meta is not astonishingly huge.

Should the most active members do something special at meta, at least to give an example?

Comment: Without answers, this question will become self-referential...

Comment: I was just about to start a new topic here about the state of the community, but find many others share the same frustration. What's wrong with DSP.SE? I'm not sure I feel warmly welcome here at all, and I'm sure I'm not alone.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac Fully agree. Why don't you feel welcome?

Comment: The lack of feedback or appreciation following a significant investment of time to write down a non-trivial answer is frustrating. I admit that my math-centric approach to DSP is not exactly mainstream, but I often feel like I'm writing for the wrong audience and despite of giving a correct answer remain completely ignored. This may just be my ego acting up, but a few more upvotes would make this much more worthwhile for me.

Comment: And allow me to add: You seem to be one of the very few people I seem to be resonating with! Thanks for that!

Comment: Count me in an equivalence relationship :) If you are in personal effects following downvoting, let me share my recent dive at Meta  http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284927/338244 Probably my concern was totally off-topic ;)

Comment: Hah! I feel with you. I think your post did not deserve that. You certainly raise an interesting point. On DSP.SE it's not only about lack of answers marked as correct, it's often that good and correct answers don't receive upvotes, and mediocre, superficial or even incorrect answers get flagged as correct.